# ApostropheCMS V3 : How to have a Selected item in one widget trigger reactively displayed content in another widget in the same page client-side

Tags: data-binding, widget, apostrophe-cms, vue-reactivity

I have 2 widgets in a Page.
The first widget displays a list of items names.
The other widget displays details of the selected item in the first widget.
Similar to filtering mecanism for piece-type.
How can I implements this kind of reactivity of widgets client-side ?

Comment: Why do they need to be separate widgets? That separation could be making things unnecessarily complicated, or maybe you need to have unrelated content in between.

Comment: Thank you Tom. The same widgets used in different multiple contexts. Selecting an item displays in one context its class definition, in another an instance  summary, in another a list of all instances of the same item type, etc. I want my design to be DRY. May be a alternative could be re-use of templates.  But I don't see how ... Any idea ?

Comment: So your goal is for a control in widget A to control the display of widget B which is located in another part of the page? You can't structure it as a single widget?

Comment: Single Widget not an option as reused independently. The goal  is bi-directional sync. Widget A displays a list of Classes, and widget B a list of related superclasses. Widget B reacts to the selection of a class in A and vice versa : A reacts to the selection of superclass in B too. The 2 widgets are usable independently in different contexts and not allways in a same page. A solution could be widget A adapt a property in the global doc and emit a custom browser event, Widget B handles this event, reads the new value of the property in the global and update itself. Vice-versa. Possible? How?

Comment: You can add attributes to event elements in widget A and write standard vanilla JavaScript to find those in your player for widget B and add change event handlers etc. Apostrophe has few opinions on front end JavaScript. You can do it with vanilla js or your framework of choice.